# Vue.js: rendering data based on class

Tags: vue.js

`enter code here`How can i render a data of the list based on the specific class

```
<div class="my-data">
<li class="list-group top">
<li class="list-group top">
<li class="list-group ">
<li class="list-group ">
</div>
```

now i want to show only the list item having class top

i have my code as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>vue js snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.13/vue.js"></script>
<!-- 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
<script src="vue.js"></script>

 -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <h1>list of players</h1>
                    <li :class="['list-group-item']"   @click="removeplayer(player, $event)"  v-for="player in players" >
                     {{player.id}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <h1>list of my players</h1>
                    <li v-show= "inas">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <pre>{{$data.players|json}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

    var examples = new Vue ({
        el: "#app",

        data:{
            players:

            [{              
                "id": 1,
                "playername": "Allen",
                "points": "8170",
                "price": "88"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "playername": "Fiona",
                "points": "6952",
                "price": "88"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "playername": "Kathleen",
                "points": "2895",
                "price": "88"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "playername": "Devin",
                "points": "9725",
                "price": "88"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "playername": "Noah",
                "points": "7453",
                "price": "88"
            }]

        },

        methods: {
            removeplayer: function (player, ev) {
                ev.target.classList.add('inas');
            }
                 }
            }); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

now what i want to do is on clicking this rendered list...i want it to be displayed within List of my players...this is like selecting your players from the list..

on click event i have added the inas class..so i want that player to be displayed within my player list

Comment: Mind editing your question a bit? Details are lacking. Even html is wrong.

Comment: Typically there'd be some sort of parameter on the data itself you could use in `v-if`or `v-show`.

Comment: v-show or v-if could be done if i have some sorts of parameter within the data.but i wan to render it from the list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your UX data driven (which is the main point of using a framework like Vue), you have two main options:

1. Change your data to include a "hidden" field on each user, use that field in a `v-if` or `v-show`, and have `removeplayer()` toggle it.
2. Change `removeplayer()` to remove the player data structure from the players array.

I usually go the route of 2. and keep two lists of the players – one as it came from the server and the second starts off as a copy of that list and gets modified by the user via Vue (e.g. by `removeplayer()`).